# Recode based on lookup table across multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to recode a number of columns, each with different recoding rules.  As far as I can tell, `dplyr::recode()` doesn't accept vectors. Preferably the solution would be tidyverse rather than a bunch of nested loops!

Here is example data and the lookup table:

```r
x <-structure(list(MAIN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                            1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PREDDEG = c(3L, 3L, 
                                                                                 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                 1L, 2L), HIGHDEG = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                      3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L), CONTROL = c(1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                           2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                           3L, 1L), not_to_recode = c("asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", 
                                                                                                                                                                                      "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", 
                                                                                                                                                                                      "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
x
#>    MAIN PREDDEG HIGHDEG CONTROL not_to_recode
#> 1     1       3       4       1          asdf
#> 2     1       3       4       1          asdf
#> 3     1       3       4       2          asdf
#> 4     1       3       4       1          asdf
#> 5     1       3       4       1          asdf
#> 6     1       3       4       1          asdf
#> 7     1       2       2       1          asdf
#> 8     1       3       3       1          asdf
#> 9     1       3       4       1          asdf
#> 10    1       3       4       1          asdf
#> 11    1       3       3       2          asdf
#> 12    1       2       2       1          asdf
#> 13    1       3       3       2          asdf
#> 14    0       3       4       3          asdf
#> 15    1       2       2       1          asdf
#> 16    1       2       2       1          asdf
#> 17    1       3       4       2          asdf
#> 18    1       1       2       1          asdf
#> 19    1       1       1       3          asdf
#> 20    1       2       2       1          asdf


lookup <- structure(list(variable_name = c("MAIN", "MAIN", "PREDDEG", "PREDDEG", "PREDDEG", "PREDDEG", "PREDDEG", "HIGHDEG", "HIGHDEG", "HIGHDEG","HIGHDEG", "HIGHDEG", "CONTROL", "CONTROL", "CONTROL"), 
                         value = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3), 
                         label = c("Not main campus", "Main campus", "Not classified", "Predominantly certificate-degree granting", "Predominantly associate's-degree granting", "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting", "Entirely graduate-degree granting", "Non-degree-granting", "Certificate degree", "Associate degree", "Bachelor's degree", "Graduate degree", "Public", "Private nonprofit", "Private for-profit")), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

lookup
#>    variable_name value                                     label
#> 1           MAIN     0                           Not main campus
#> 2           MAIN     1                               Main campus
#> 3        PREDDEG     0                            Not classified
#> 4        PREDDEG     1 Predominantly certificate-degree granting
#> 5        PREDDEG     2 Predominantly associate's-degree granting
#> 6        PREDDEG     3  Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting
#> 7        PREDDEG     4         Entirely graduate-degree granting
#> 8        HIGHDEG     0                       Non-degree-granting
#> 9        HIGHDEG     1                        Certificate degree
#> 10       HIGHDEG     2                          Associate degree
#> 11       HIGHDEG     3                         Bachelor's degree
#> 12       HIGHDEG     4                           Graduate degree
#> 13       CONTROL     1                                    Public
#> 14       CONTROL     2                         Private nonprofit
#> 15       CONTROL     3                        Private for-profit
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Split the long form of the lookup by `variable_name` and sort it by `names` within `x`

```
slook <- split(lookup[-1], lookup$variable_name)[names(x)]
```

Then use `mapply` to do a table lookup restricted to just the values in each variable separately:

```
 mapply(function(a,b){  b[['label']][match(a, b$value)]}, x, slook)
      MAIN              PREDDEG                                     HIGHDEG              CONTROL             
 [1,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Public"            
 [2,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Public"            
 [3,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Private nonprofit" 
 [4,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Public"            
 [5,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Public"            
 [6,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Public"            
 [7,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly associate's-degree granting" "Associate degree"   "Public"            
 [8,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Bachelor's degree"  "Public"            
 [9,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Public"            
[10,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Public"            
[11,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Bachelor's degree"  "Private nonprofit" 
[12,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly associate's-degree granting" "Associate degree"   "Public"            
[13,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Bachelor's degree"  "Private nonprofit" 
[14,] "Not main campus" "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Private for-profit"
[15,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly associate's-degree granting" "Associate degree"   "Public"            
[16,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly associate's-degree granting" "Associate degree"   "Public"            
[17,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting"  "Graduate degree"    "Private nonprofit" 
[18,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly certificate-degree granting" "Associate degree"   "Public"            
[19,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly certificate-degree granting" "Certificate degree" "Private for-profit"
[20,] "Main campus"     "Predominantly associate's-degree granting" "Associate degree"   "Public"
```

To address the concern raised about the example that didn't match the task: One can restrict the assignment to just those columns whose names are in the names present in the `lookup` object:

```
 x[ , names(slook)] <-  mapply(
   function(a,b){  b[['label']][  # the character label col
                         match(a, b$value) ]},  # lookup x-index in slook 
                     # end function call, now the arguments
                   x[names(slook)], # arg matched to `a`
                   slook,   #arg gets matched to `b`
                   SIMPLIFY=FALSE)  # keep it a list rather than make a matrix
> x
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   MAIN            PREDDEG                                   HIGHDEG            CONTROL            not_to_recode
   <chr>           <chr>                                     <chr>              <chr>              <chr>        
 1 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Public             asdf         
 2 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Public             asdf         
 3 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Private nonprofit  asdf         
 4 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Public             asdf         
 5 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Public             asdf         
 6 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Public             asdf         
 7 Main campus     Predominantly associate's-degree granting Associate degree   Public             asdf         
 8 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Bachelor's degree  Public             asdf         
 9 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Public             asdf         
10 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Public             asdf         
11 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Bachelor's degree  Private nonprofit  asdf         
12 Main campus     Predominantly associate's-degree granting Associate degree   Public             asdf         
13 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Bachelor's degree  Private nonprofit  asdf         
14 Not main campus Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Private for-profit asdf         
15 Main campus     Predominantly associate's-degree granting Associate degree   Public             asdf         
16 Main campus     Predominantly associate's-degree granting Associate degree   Public             asdf         
17 Main campus     Predominantly bachelor's-degree granting  Graduate degree    Private nonprofit  asdf         
18 Main campus     Predominantly certificate-degree granting Associate degree   Public             asdf         
19 Main campus     Predominantly certificate-degree granting Certificate degree Private for-profit asdf         
20 Main campus     Predominantly associate's-degree granting Associate degree   Public             asdf
```

If you want to emulate the actions of `mapply`, I believe that similar functionality is offered in the `purrr`-package which is in the tidyverse orbit. Specifically, you should be looking at `map2`:

```
 help(map2, pac=purrr)  # attention to `pmap`
```

Comment: Thanks.  This fails when using the full dataset where there are columns that don't get recoded.  I've updated my example data with a non-recoding column.  Also, for others, I'd love to be able to do this in tidyverse rather than base since it is so hard to disentangel what's happening with base R apply functions and indexing.

Comment: You could use `Map` instead of `mapply` and skip the `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` too

Comment: Likewise, replacing `b[[2]]` with `b$label` might make it more explicit what is being subset out.

Comment: I took a half-way step in the direction of your last suggestion.